Empty Material 3 TextField with label jumps when it gets focus
Empty Material 3 TextField with label jumps when it gets focus
Affected platforms
Kotlin version*: 2.0.20
Compose Multiplatform version*: 1.7.0-alpha03
Device (model or simulator for iOS issues): Xiaomi Redmi Note 10S
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("Hello")
        TextField(TextFieldValue(), {}, label = { Text("Label 1") })
        TextField(TextFieldValue(), {}, label = { Text("Label 2") })
    }
}

Expected behavior
It doesn't jump when it gets focus
